# Datagridview tab order

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, desktop-application

I want to set tab order in datagridview something like this.

```
product name | unit price  | qty | amount
```

I want that the moment I select product ,qty cell should be selected. Once I enter the qty and hit tab then it should go to next row..

this is what I have tried so far

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
    {
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell = GetNextCell(dataGridView1.CurrentCell);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}

private DataGridViewCell GetNextCell(DataGridViewCell currentCell)
{
    int i = 0;
    DataGridViewCell nextCell = currentCell;

    do
    {
        int nextCellIndex = (nextCell.ColumnIndex + 1) % dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
        int nextRowIndex = nextCellIndex == 0 ? (nextCell.RowIndex + 1) % dataGridView1.RowCount 
        : nextCell.RowIndex;
        nextCell = dataGridView1.Rows[nextRowIndex].Cells[nextCellIndex];
        i++;
    } while (i < dataGridView1.RowCount * dataGridView1.ColumnCount && nextCell.ReadOnly);

    return nextCell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to understand what your requirements are. So, I am guessing this may be what you are looking for.

If the goal is to only allow the user to enter values into the “quantity” cell, and force the grids selection to always be a cell in the “quantity” column, then it appears you may be making this more complicated that it has to be.

You commented…

> *”I want that the moment I select product ,qty cell should be selected.”*

You are not specific as to if you mean ANY other cell in the row or ONLY the “Product” cell. I will assume you mean ANY cell. If this is the case, then I suggest you wire up the grids `CellMouseUp` event and simply set the “Quantity” cell as the selected cell. Something like…

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseUp(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"];
}
```

In relation to moving around in the grid, it appears you have the `Tab` key working in an overly complicated way and this can be simplified. My question is what if the user presses the right or left arrow keys? The current code is not checking for this and the user could move the grids selected cell to another cell that is NOT the “Quantity” column. I am guessing you may want to check for these keys also.

The code below will also fulfill the second requirement…

> *"Once I enter the qty and hit tab then it should go to next row.."*

Below is the grids `KeyUp` event with a simplified version of moving the `Tab` key, in addition to adding a check for the right and left Arrow keys.

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  DataGridViewRow curRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) {
    if (curRow.Index == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1) {
      dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Quantity"];
    }
    else {
      dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[curRow.Index + 1].Cells["Quantity"];
    }
  }
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right || e.KeyCode == Keys.Left) {
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[curRow.Index].Cells["Quantity"];
  }
}
```

Edit per OP comment...

Again, you need to "edit" your question and make it clear what behavior you are wanting when the user presses the Tab key. From you comment I can only guess below is what you are looking for.

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  DataGridViewCell curCell = dataGridView1.CurrentCell;
  DataGridViewRow curRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
  switch (e.KeyCode) {
    case Keys.Tab:
      if (dataGridView1.Columns[curCell.ColumnIndex].Name == "Amount") {
        if (curRow.Index == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1) {
          dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["ProductName"];
        }
        else {
          dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[curRow.Index + 1].Cells["ProductName"];
        }
      }
      else {
        if (dataGridView1.Columns[curCell.ColumnIndex].Name == "UnitPrice") {
          dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1.Rows[curRow.Index].Cells["Quantity"];
        }
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: If i select product from grid then qty cell should be selected and once i enter quantity then i press tab then it should take me to next row product name cell

Comment: @user9914033 … What do you mean by… _”If i select product from grid then qty cell should be selected…”_ … this is fine and doable, however you continue with… _”and once i enter quantity then i press tab then it should take me to next row product name cell”_ ….? … If the code moves the selection to the “product” call then your first comment does not apply? This is a contradiction… you can’t have it both ways. You should edit your question and clearly describe what behavior you are looking for when the Tab key is pressed.

Comment: here is the requirement

Comment: if user select product then qty cell should be selected so that he does not have to go to unit price and amount cell,and after specifying qty,next row product cell should be selected

Comment: @user9914033... What do you mean by... _"If user select product."_ ... ? Does the user "CLICK" on the product cell to "select product" ? Does the user "TAB" to "select product"? As I previously stated the first part of you comment...."select product"... and the last part... _"next row product cell should be selected"_ ... doesn't make sense and is a contradiction. You are not making yourself clear on what you want.